# Iterate through raw text in Python to separate questions and answers in a PDF

Tags: python-3.x, pdf, nltk

**Using Python 3.7:**

I have a PDF document that I am converting to raw text using textract. The PDF consists of a Table of Contents, and then a series of questions and answers, for example:

**-TOC:**

content of TOC

**-Question 1:**

content of question 1

**-Answer 1:**

content of answer 1

**-Question 2:**

content of question 2

**-Answer 2:**

content of answer 2

etc...

I managed to convert the PDF to text:

```
import textract
text = textract.process(PATHtoPDF, encoding='ascii')
```

**My question is: How can one iterate through the text to isolate the question and its respective answer to get the question and answer in a single string?**

**I tried** to use NLTK to search for the phrase "Question 1:", but I could not figure out how to isolate all the text between "Question 1:", and "Question 2:".

**I also tried** to convert the PDF to HTML to try to preserve the headings of the questions and answers, but there are many other items being flagged as headings with the word "Question :1" from the Table of Contents.

Any thoughts as to what can be done here?

Thanks!

Comment: If the format of the PDF is fixed, like you have mentioned then you can use regex to parse the text.

Comment: Do you have any materials / manuals you can reference for me to try?

Comment: You can refer the documentation -- https://docs.python.org/3.7/library/re.html, else share the exact format of the PDF, i can create regex for you.